# How to get record name passing object name, record id dynamically

Tags: visualforce

I am getting record id from Browser URL and I got the Object name using record ID. now I want to fetch the record name using record id.

I used dynamic query to fetch name using record id but I am getting error can anyone help to solve my issue.

Browser URL: https://ap1.salesforce.com/500900000070l0d

Record ID: 500900000070l0d

I fetched object name: Match =case

BrowserURLID =500900000070l0d

Dynamic Query:

```
  string qr = 'select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id=:'+BrowserURLId;
```

> Error : I unexpected token: '500900000070l'

Can anyone please help where I did mistake or any other way to get record name using Object name and ID pass dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it almost right with the bind variable. Try this

```
string qr = 'select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id=:BrowserURLId';
```

I confess I like this version (with bind variable inside the query and not as concatenated Id) better, harder for anyone to pass `&BrowserUrlId=500900000070l OR isDeleted = false` and retrieve all cases. It's called [SOQL Injection](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm)

(Would be extra awesome if you'd also check if match is one of valid values you expect, compare with a `Set<String>{'Case', 'Account'}` etc. or even a result of `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keyset()`)

---

If you really really want to play with string building (I advise against):

```
string qr = 'select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id=\'' + BrowserURLId + '\'';
```

(@Prady - you forgot about escaping the apostrophes ;))

Comment: oh yes.. i missed that one... Good catch :)

Comment: For more details you can check this Blog http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2012/09/using-variables-in-dynamic-soql.html

Comment: It solved my problem: Thanks For your help.............Mylife

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your query should be

```
string qr = 'select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id='+BrowserURLId;
```

Remove the **:** as SF would look for variable called 500900000070l

Comment: Dear Prady,
 As per my understand “500900000070l” is not a variable; that is record id number (BrowserURLId=500900000070l0d).

Comment: Your query  would be interpreted by SF as select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id=:500900000070l; So the SF thinks that there is a variable called 500900000070l, which obviously is not there. Thats the reason you get this error. If you remove the : the query would be interpreted as select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id='500900000070l';

Comment: dynamic query do not need binding variables when u say BrowserURLId SF looks for the variable BrowserURLId

Comment: I passed record id through variable BrowserURLId. In this scenario BrowserURLId dynamically passed record id value is 500900000070l0d.

Comment: Change your query to string qr = 'select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id='+BrowserURLId; and let me know what you get

Comment: string qr = 'select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id='+BrowserURLId;
list<sObject> result =Database.query(qr); Same Error: I unexpected token: '500900000070l'

Comment: Can you add a debug statement for qr and see what you get there

Comment: The solution von @Prady is ok, you just need to mask the quotes like this: `string qr = 'select id, CaseNumber from '+match+' where id='\''+BrowserURLId+'\'';`

Comment: @mast0r i missed on that... eyescream and you caught that at the same time..